# AWS ELB endpoint in Godaddy

Tags: amazon-web-services, godaddy, amazon-elb, wildcard-subdomain

I have my domain name regsitered in Godaddy. I have my servers in AWS. We use a public ELB to redirect traffic to our webservers inside a VPC in a public subnet. I want to point one of my subdomain name to the elastic loadbalancer endpoint and I want to do it in Godaddy itself and not route53.

I know I cant point my elb endpoint to an A record, What can I do to point my subdomain name to an ELB endpoint in Godaddy?

My main domain name is pointed to a different site. So I cant use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use a `CNAME` record, something like

```
my.web.thingy.org        CNAME  my-loadbalancer-1234567890.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com.
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-domain-names-with-elb.html

---

[Edit; response to comment]: There is no need for you to set any `A` record.  You just point your name to the ELB name Amazon has provided you, and their nameservers will map that to an IP address.  You don't want to look up that IP address and try to shortcut things by using it yourself, because it can (and in my experience *does*) change regularly.  Just use the name Amazon provides you per their instructions.

Comment: I have my main domain name being used for my main site and I need this elb endpoint for subdomain only. How can I do it then?

Comment: @ArjunPrasad You still use a CNAME.

Comment: @EEAA Can you let me know how? I cant figure it out. Where will I point my A record to?

Comment: As the person above said, you use a CNAME record, not an A record.

Comment: How can I setup a CNAME record without A record?